# Do i need to use template?

Tags: c++

i hope you're having a great day! :)

I got this main() code, and i need to make it so it works.

> 1) I can use only 1 class; 2) Avoid code duplication 3) You cannnot change main() function

Few quesions i want to ask:

1. Do i need to use templates?
2. How can i get more than 1 object ( dog./peroson ) if i'm able to use only 1 class? :)

   ```
   int main() {
    Person p("Jon",22);
    Dog d("Rex","Beagle");
    p.printInfo();
    d.printInfo();
   return 0;

   }
   ```

Comment: Condition 1) is completely unrealistic.

Comment: `Person` , `Dog` thats two different classes, no template will change that fact. Unless you do some trickery like `typedef Dog Person;`

Comment: `typedef Person Dog;`

Comment: @Steeve I would prefer to see a dog as a person rather than calling a person "dog" :P

Comment: @davidhigh well this was a class work, i'm a bit sick so i'm trying to catch them up by learning on my own :)

Comment: what is the whole point of this exercise? I mean you could even make this code run without a single class by using some dirty macros, but why? What do you mean with "so it works"? What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: @tobi303 I think you are right, but in this case it doesn't really matter, they will just become synonyms ;)

Comment: @tobi303 the point is to learn templates/STL or what ever... im just stuck home so i'm trying to complete the class work to understand how it all works :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that with templates. It seems like you have a misunderstanding of what a template is.

This is a class template:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo { T value; }
```

Note that this is not a class. It is just a template. Only when you instantiate the template, e.g.

```
Foo<int> f;
Foo<double> g;
```

then the compiler will create the necessary code, that would be

```
struct Foo<int> { int value; }
struct Foo<double> { double value; }
```

and those are two classes, not one!

If you really want to get this with one class, the only way would be to use an alias like this:

```
typedef Dog Person;
```

However, I stronly doubt that this is the point of the exercise. If it really is about templates, the only explanation I have is that you misunderstood something and you are actually supposed to use two classes that (maybe) should be two different instantiations of the same template, eg something like this..

```
typedef Foo<int> Dog;
typedef Foo<double> Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i came up with this solution, maybe this helps someone.

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;
#include <cmath>


template <class T1, class T2>
class Person {
        T1 attr1;
        T2 attr2;
    public:
        Person(T1 a1, T2 a2) {
            attr1 = a1; attr2 = a2;
        }
        void printInfo() {
            cout <<"Hi my name is "<< attr1 << " and i'm ' " << attr2 << endl;
        }
};
typedef Person<string,int> Personn;
typedef Person<string,string> Dog;
int main() {

 Personn p("Jon",22);
 Dog d("Rex","Beagle");
 p.printInfo();
 d.printInfo();
return 0;

}
```